# Accept and record condition value from received HTML email form

Tags: php, html, html-email

I'm trying to figure out with email confirmation function via email, received by user.

If I have `<input type='submit' value='Accept' id='btn1'>`, (which is correct way shown by [ADyson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5947043/adyson), instead  double quotes: `<input type="submit" value="Accept" id="btn1">`), then how do I use `PHP` `$_POST['acceptval']` for confirmation from this `HTML`, which must record value  to `MySQL` database from received message form by included `ID`, then to pass this condition from the website.

So, if I will include  `require 'connect.php';` to code below, and will get data for `to`, `message`, `subject`, I will receive message to my  `userreceiveremail@gmail.com`, then I want allow user press button, and record value to his record field, but I can't figure out, how it works:

```
 <?php
    $to = "userreceiveremail@gmail.com";
    $subject = "Confirmation notification";

    $message = "
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Accept registration</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p>Hello, dear User! Please, accept your registration</p>
    <input type='submit' value='Accept' id='btn1'>
    </body>
    </html>
    ";

    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

    $headers .= 'From: <senderemail@gmail.com>' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Cc: Some text' . "\r\n";

    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

    echo "Mail sent successfully";
    ?>
```

Maybe my scenario does not correspond to the classic  or correct approach to solving this particular task, because I'm just trying to figure out, how to get desired result, anyway yet I can't find any close example for this.

Any advice, guide or example would be very helpful

Comment: If you tried to add `<input type="submit" value="Accept" id="btn1">` into the $message string then of course it will fail because the double-quotes mess up the PHP string. You'd need to escape them, or use single quotes. But I would not recommend putting forms into emails - many email clients do not support or allow them. instead just give the user a link back to a dedicated URL in your application. You can add a unique identifier (e.g. a GUID perhaps) to the URL as a parameter if you need to identify the specific user. Look at how popular sites implement this kind of thing, and follow that

Comment: @ADyson Hello! So, this sounds   correct:  "just give the user a link back to a dedicated URL in your application" Can you provide some  guide on "unique identifier (e.g. a GUID perhaps) to the URL as a parameter if you need to identify the specific user."  according "popular sites"

Comment: you'd want to generate a URL something like `https://www.example.com/ConfirmRegistration.php?id=232d3dfa-d254-440f-a4a1-4297c3aad10c`. In your database you would store this GUID in a column against the user's record. So when you receive a request to ConfirmRegistration.php it can compare to see if this value matches any of the values stored in your database. If it does, then you can confirm the user's registration (if they haven't already confirmed it previously).

Comment: PHP can generate a GUID (if you have an extension installed) - see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.com-create-guid.php . Or most databases can do it (the time when you create the user's database record would be a great time to do it, and then save immediately into the column) - e.g. for MySQL you could use [UUID()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid) - I use this in a site of mine and it works nicely for a similar task. (N.B. A UUID and a GUID are similar enough for your purposes to be interchangeable.)

Comment: P.S. in relation to "popular sites" i could perhaps have said "almost every site" - you'll find if you register for something and then get a confirmation email, the button in that email will generally link you to a URL with a similar pattern to the one I've just suggested, containing one or more unique variables related to your account in the query parameters. This allows the site to identify your account and confirm it without yet allowing or requiring you to log in for that purpose. It's such a common pattern that you will 99% certainly have used a link like that, even if you didn't notice.

Comment: @ADyson Ok, thank you!  I will follow your advice, and will notice you later with results

Comment: `Input` fields are not read by Outlook, just an FYI. You might link to an online for form Outlooks and the handful of emails that do read `input` will show a message saying similar to: your data is going over non secure channel. here is a list of email clients where input functionality works: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/selectors/checked/

Comment: @ADyson Hello, I have followed your advice, and have reached failure with unique identifier string, it is solved by using of GUID, but I'm trying to figure out, why md5 string fails and same time works successfully  in similar examples, please check my post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57813383/unique-identifier-link-value-receiving-failure-in-php-isset-get

Comment: @L_O: I suggested instrumenting your code to determine 1) exactly where it's failing and  2) if you see any differences between expected and actual (md5?) values.  Q: Have you done this?  Q: Could you update your post with what you've found?