# Unique identifier link value receiving failure in PHP isset GET

Tags: php, html-email, uniqueidentifier

I'm trying to verify registration via email with sending of unique identifier link to user.

I use it from remote server. Server, username, password, database values are correct, works fine with other `.php`-s, only difference `verify.php` has connection included, instead  `require 'connection.php';`, but I'm not sure if connection produces following failure.

Sends:

```
$message = "<p>Hello, dear $user</p><a href='https://mypage.info/php/reg/verify.php?vkey=$vkey'>Confirm Account</a>";
```

and receives on email:

```
https://mypage.info/php/reg/verify.php?vkey=4bf65cf02210b304143589e6dc3714c0
```

link to `verify.php`, but `php` throws `Something went wrong`, or
if instead `die` I'll check `echo 'VKey: '. $vkey;` or `echo $mysqli->error;` shows nothing.

Seems like by some reason `if (isset($_GET['vkey']))` does not receives `vkey` correctly. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here:

*Alert! This example code shows insecure method since accepts SQL parameters  directly from user input. Requires [Prepared Statements and Bound Parameters](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp), [real_escape_string()](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_real_escape_string.asp)*

```
<?php
  if (isset($_GET['vkey'])) {
     $vkey = $_GET['vkey'];
     $mysqli = NEW MySQLi ('server','username','password','db');
     $resultSet = $mysqli->query("SELECT verified, vkey FROM registration WHERE verified = 0 AND vkey = '$vkey' LIMIT 1");

     if ($resultSet->num_rows == 1)
     {
         $update = $mysqli->query("UPDATE registration SET verified = 1 WHERE vkey = '$vkey' LIMIT 1");

         if($update){
            echo "Your account has been verified. You may now login.";
         } else {
            echo $mysqli->error;
         }
     } 
     else 
     {
         echo "This account invalid or already verified";
     }
    } else {
     die("Something went wrong");
  }
?>
```

Comment: For starters, PLEASE always use [prepared statements and parameterized queries](https://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/a-guide-to-mysql-prepared-statements-and-parameterized-queries.html).  NEVER accept SQL parameters directly from user input.  Never!  ALSO: Does your code ever get called?  You're checking for a POST ... but it looks like your URL is a GET.

Comment: @paulsm4 Yes, sure, this is just example code without prepared statements, and I've include alert above, but what about POST it was error in my topic, in all cases I mean and use GET here, please recheck my edit

Comment: just a note regarding your "Alert!" section. When you come to do that task, you don't need prepared statements **and** real_escape_string. Just prepared statements and parameters is enough. real_escape_string is not necessary if you use parameters.

Comment: Anyway there's nothing in the code above which would indicate why this is failing. i suggest checking your webserver logs to see what actual URLs are being received and whether they are structured correctly.

Comment: Good advice!  L_O should instrument each step in his PHP (as I suggested below).  He should *ALSO* check his Apache "access.log" and verify the URL being received is *EXACTLY* the URL he expects.

Comment: @L_O: Any luck?  Please update your post with your current status.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks in the $_POST array instead of $_GET

```
  if (isset($_GET['vkey'])) {
     $vkey = $_GET['vkey'];
```

Comment: I think you're on the right track.  I have no idea who downvoted you, or why :(

Comment: @suspectus Hello, sorry I did not down-voted your answer, someone else did, but  I've checked with POST instead GET and  got same result. Seems like it is something else here

Comment: The example code was incorrect using $_POST.  Hence the -1 I guess. Corrected.

Comment: @L_O if you get the `die` message, `$_GET['vkey']` is not set. Can you check web server access log to see what the actual URL received is?

Comment: @suspectus Well, I have used md5 unique identifier by time and name for vkey, and now I've checked it with GUID, by some reason same code works fine and verifies user, but I have another code, which uses md5 with almost same scenario, except email, but using it with GET or POST and  it works fine

Comment: @suspectus Yes, but now it is not clear why md5 string failures in this particular example, it looks normal string 4bf65cf02210b304143589e6dc3714c0 without any anomalies,  and it is widely used in many examples  with similar functionality

Answer (score -1):

SUGGESTION: instrument everything possible, and post back what you find.

For example:

```
<?php
  echo "vkey=" . $_GET['vkey'] . "...<br/>";
  if (isset($_GET['vkey'])) {
     $vkey = $_GET['vkey'];
     echo "vkey=" . $vkey . "...<br/>";
     $mysqli = NEW MySQLi ('server','username','password','db');
     echo "mysqli: SUCCEEDED...<br/>";
     $resultSet = $mysqli->query("SELECT verified, vkey FROM registration WHERE verified = 0 AND vkey = '$vkey' LIMIT 1");
     echo "resultSet: SUCCEEDED...<br/>";

     echo "resultSet->num_rows=" . $resultSet->num_rows . "...<br/>";
     if ($resultSet->num_rows == 1)
     {
         $update = $mysqli->query("UPDATE registration SET verified = 1 WHERE vkey = '$vkey' LIMIT 1");
         echo "update: SUCCEEDED...<br/>");

         if($update){
            echo "Your account has been verified. You may now login.";
         } else {
            echo $mysqli->error;
         }
     } 
     else 
     {
         echo "This account invalid or already verified";
     }
    } else {
      echo "ERROR STATE: " . $mysqli->error . "...<br/>";
     die("Something went wrong");
  }
?>
```

And no, I can't think of "... why md5 string" could be the culprit.  But I think the above instrument (or similar) might help us determine EXACTLY where the problem is occurring ... and thus how to resolve it.

'Hope that helps...